# Filter date entries based on week and year

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I have made an overview-page that shows all shifts in a certain web app (as shown in the attached picture).

[image]

As the image shows, I have visually made the two  inputs where the user can specify both the year and week where a shift takes place. However, my Shift table is currently comprised of a start and endtime in the DateTime-format, e.g. 2020-01-29 15:00:00.

What would be the best way to filter these entries in this way?

Comment: We kind of need to see the table

Comment: In what do you want to filter it I don't get it

Comment: I want the page to only display the entries of a certain week or year. The table looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/Gu2SXHn

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE YEAR(CREATED_DATE) = 2020 AND WEEK(CREATED_DATE) = 5;
```

Comment: Note that this solution uses functions on the table columns (as oppposed to the target values), so if we're  genuinely looking for 'best', then this isn't going to be it.

Comment: @Strawberry: the 'best' you mentioned is all about speed/performance. If it's true for OP, of course create additional indexed columns will achieve that goal easily. But if the filter operations are not crucial or frequently used and/or OP do not want or can't add extra columns for any reason, use functions is not too bad, especially when table size is small. The 'best' in reality depends on various factors.

Comment: Filter options will be used quite a bit, but the current system will not be that big / have that many users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql raw query to filter results with year and week number.
Just send correct ajax request on server with filter parameters (year, weeknumber)
For example: if user enters year 2020 and week 34.

```php
$data = YourModel::query()
    ->where(...)
    ->whereRaw('YEAR(created_at) = ?', [$request->year])
    ->whereRaw('DAYOFYEAR(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?', [7 * ($request->weeknumber - 1), 7 *  $request->weeknumber])
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: So i should linkt this method in the controller to the filter button right?

Comment: Yes, you should make route for data filtering then return filtered data. You can use ajax or other method to do that